# Adding multiple String objects from an arraylist to an array using .add() and a for loop

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

In this method, I am trying to return a regular array of the String representation of all of the objects that are currently stored in an arraylist of type MediaItem called itemList. (This is also described in the comments before my code.) This method is part of a larger MediaList project that contains several subclasses, which are each different types of media (song, book, video game, etc).

My problem is that when I run the code and attempt to print the String array, it only prints the first String object that was the arraylist. My loop is only adding the first MediaItem object to the String array, instead of looping through and adding each successive object. Why is this?

Here is my code, along with the instructions that my professor gave us:

```
 /** TODO 11: implement this method.
   *  This method returns an array of the String representation of all of 
   *  the MediaItem objects that are currently stored in the itemList.
   *  A String representation of a MediaItem is returned by calling its 
    toString() method. 
   *  The array returned may not contain any NULL values. This method returns 
    an array of 
   *  length 0 if the itemList is empty.
   **/
   public String[] getItemListAsStringArray(){
      ArrayList<String> itemListAsString = new ArrayList<String>();
      for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
         itemListAsString.add(itemList.get(i).toString());
         String[] stringArray = itemListAsString.toArray(new String[0]);
         if (stringArray.length == 0) {
            return stringArray;
         }
         else {
            itemListAsString.add(itemList.get(i).toString()); 
            return stringArray;
         }
      }
      String[] stringArray = itemListAsString.toArray(new String[0]);
      return stringArray;
   }
```

I had to make a new  arraylist to add the objects to, because the original arraylist is of type . I then had to convert that arraylist (which I named "itemListAsString") to a regular array so that I was able return it at the end of the method (I checked with my professor, we are supposed to convert to a regular array).

I tried using a debugger, and it looked like the code was adding the first object, and then looping through and trying to add that exact same object again. It would then exit the loop. Since I'm using a for loop, shouldn't the code move on to the next object in the arraylist instead of trying to add the same one?

Comment: What's `itemList`?  Is it's Length 0?

Comment: @jiveturkey as I mentioned, itemList is an arraylist of type MediaItem. It does not have a specified length.

Comment: You return inside the loop instead of after the loop, so you return the array as soon as the first item has been added to the list.

Comment: @DavidConrad oh jeez, okay thank you. So I should get rid of that return statement inside the loop, and keep the one that is outside of it at the very end? Edit: so I guess I don't need the if/else statements at all? The code seems to work correctly without them.

Comment: Yes, you've got it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more modern way of doing the same thing:

```
public String[] getItemListAsStringArray() {
    return itemList.stream()
                   .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                   .map(Object::toString)
                   .toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

They're equivalent in terms of functionality, but this way has some of the benefits and drawbacks of functional programming. Basically: code written this way is usually much less error prone, but it comes at a cost.

Comment: Thanks. I wish my professor had taught us that as well, it looks much cleaner than what I wrote.

Comment: No, you're fine. Your way of doing it is definitely still valid, and likely more efficient (though I'd switch from index-based loops to [foreach loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html))

Comment: Yeah, I used regular for loops since I am more familiar with them than with for/each ones, but those would have looked less cluttered and still worked.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected my code thanks your help, this is the corrected code:

```
public String[] getItemListAsStringArray(){
  ArrayList<String> itemListAsString = new ArrayList<String>();

  for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
     itemListAsString.add(itemList.get(i).toString());
  }

  String[] stringArray = itemListAsString.toArray(new String[0]);
  return stringArray;
  }
```